# How to delete all the values that starts with a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have the below dataframe.

```
df=
s.no., name, ratings, price
0   Microwave Oven Sharp 20 Litres, White, R-20AS-W,    5.0 out of 5 stars, SAR 199.00
1   Geepas 20 Liter Microwave Oven - GMO1894,   SAR 186.00, SAR 186.00
2   REBUNE ELECTRIC OVEN 10L, RE1016,   SAR 149.00, SAR 149.00
3   Gas stove auto ignition 2 burner,   SAR 240.00, SAR 240.00
4   Nikai Microwave - 20 LTR -NMO515N8N,    5.0 out of 5 stars, SAR 192.15
```

From the ratings column I want to remove all values that starts with SAR and replace it with "No Ratings".

the output has to be as below:

```
df=
    s.no., name, ratings, price
    0   Microwave Oven Sharp 20 Litres, White, R-20AS-W,    5.0 out of 5 stars, SAR 199.00
    1   Geepas 20 Liter Microwave Oven - GMO1894,   No Ratings, SAR 186.00
    2   REBUNE ELECTRIC OVEN 10L, RE1016,   No Ratings, SAR 149.00
    3   Gas stove auto ignition 2 burner,   No Ratings, SAR 240.00
    4   Nikai Microwave - 20 LTR -NMO515N8N,    5.0 out of 5 stars, SAR 192.15
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please make our work easier by providing copy pastable code, e.g. your `df` is not restructuble with `pd.read_clipboard()`. Please have a look at [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would like to achieve can be done with `str.replace`.

Setup

```
In[1]: df = pd.DataFrame([["SAR 186.00", 12], ["5 out of 5 stars", 13]], columns=['ratings', 'something'])

#df
Out[2]:         ratings         something
          0     SAR 186.00          12
          1     5 out of 5 stars    13

In[3]: df['ratings'] = df.ratings.str.replace("SAR \d+.\d+", "no rating", regex=True)
Out[4]:     ratings         something
       0    no rating           12
       1    5 out of 5 stars    13
```